# Node.js - How can I check if a parsed json has the same structure of a class?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm send a complex JSON string to my server, the following is a simple example:

```
{ 
  "a": 1;
  "b": "test"
  "c": [
      {
         "d":2
         "e":3
      },
      {
         "d":2
         "e":3
      }
  ] 
}
```

Now I want check if this object has the correct structure. For example I want check if the json above has three attributes: `"a"` , `"b"` and a list of value `"d"` and `"e"` called `"c"`. The problem is that my object is very large and I can't check every single attribute, I've not find an easy and rapid solution.

Comment: Uhhh, how do you expect to verify every single property without checking every  single property?  If you want to verify "every single attribute", you are going to have to "check every single attribute" so I don't know why you say you "can't check every single attribute".  That makes no sense.

Comment: You could try JSON Schema (http://json-schema.org/).

Answer (score 0):

[JSON schema](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonschema) is one popular solution. It allows you to compare your prewritten json schema against an instance/json.

If you don't want to use any third party library, you can parse your `JSON` to `string` and find if each attribute exists. But there are too many corner cases here.